# Performance Comparison between DoubleDQN & DQN

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I tried DoubleDQN and DQN algorithm on gym NChain game and realized that the performance of DoubleDQN was not more stable or better than DQN.

I set batch size of the training after each action taken to be 1. May I know this is the reason of DoubleDQN not outperforming DQN?

[Result Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Y1o.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both of your networks learned nothing or the environment doesn't cause optimistic in Q value. The original result of the n chain is **3643**.  [A Bayesian Framework for Reinforcement Learning](http://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~shiry/lecture/machine-learning/papers/BRL-2000.pdf)

In atari, Dobule DQN outperforms DQN in most of the games but have worse results in a few ones. 
[image]